# How can I get values from both my tables?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Let's say I have to MySQL tables like this.

TBL_1

```
ID - NAME - DESCRIPTION
1    foo    very nice
```

TBL_2

```
ID - PRICE - CATEGORY - QUANTITY
1     10        a          5
```

If I was to set up a PDO instance like so....

```
<?php 
  $handler = new PDO("XXXX;XXXXX","XXX","XXX");

  $query = $handler->query('SELECT * FROM TBL_1');
  while($r = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {

    echo $r->id;       
    echo $r->name;
    echo $r->description;

    //echo $r->price;
    //echo $r->category;
    //echo $r->quantity;
  }
```

How can I access `price`, `category`, `quantity` where the `ID`'s, in both tables are equal to each other?

So for example, it would come out like this.

`1 foo very nice  10 a 5`

Comment: I would highly encourage you to read up on table joins before proceeding any further.

Comment: consider to read about `JOIN` in `mysql`

Comment: A little bit more effort would have been appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use `JOIN`:

```
SELECT name, description, price, category, quantity
FROM TBL_1
JOIN TBL_2
USING (id)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `ID` columns contain the same values (i.e. a foreign key constrait exists because the values represent the same entity), you'll want to execute a query with an `INNER JOIN` on that column. By default with an `INNER JOIN`, if the requested value (for instance a `WHERE 'ID' = 3` clause) does not exist in either table, no results will be returned. Try the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM `TBL_1` AS `t1`
INNER JOIN `TBL_2` AS `t2` ON `t1`.`ID` = `t2`.`ID`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just do an `INNER JOIN` on the table where on each table the `id` is equal.

```
SELECT * FROM TBL_1 INNER JOIN TBL_2 ON TBL_1.ID=TBL_2.ID;
```